# `This field required error` though it's not defined in Model data table

Tags: django

I try to create a new article with model data:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    STATUS = (
        (0,  'normal'),
        (-1, 'deleted'),
    )
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    block = models.ForeignKey(Block, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField() # set the widget
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

However, when I submitted data from browser, it prompted that `comment` field is required thought it's not one of Article's fields.

I add a test command `print(form.errors.as_data())` in CBV `class ArticleCreateView(View):`

```
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8001/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
{'comment': [ValidationError(['This field is required.'])]}
[09/Jun/2018 22:50:16] "POST /article/create/1 HTTP/1.1" 200 3694
```

I have other table `Comment` whose ForeignKey is article

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    STATUS = (
        (0,  'normal'),
        (-1, 'deleted'),
    )
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    comment = models.TextField() # set the widget
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.comment
```

The views.py

```
class ArticleCreateView(View):

    template_name = "article/article_create.html"

    def get(self, request, block_id):
        block = Block.objects.get(id=block_id)
        context = {'b':block}
        return render(request, self.template_name,context)

    def post(self, request, block_id):

        block = Block.objects.get(id=block_id)
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            article = form.save(commit=False)
            article.owner = request.user
            article.block = block
            article.status = 0
            article.save()
            return redirect(f"/article/list/{ block_id }")
        else:
            print(form.errors.as_data())
            context = {'b':block,
                        "form":form}
            return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```

I had no idea why it throw such an error?

Comment: Could you show the `ArticleCreateView`? Maybe there are typos somewhere?

Comment: posted it, thank you. @Ralf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view, it says `CommentForm`.

```
class ArticleCreateView(View):
    def post(self, request, block_id):
        ...
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
```

Maybe you wanted to use something like `ArticleForm` or whatever you have in your code?